# JBoss Configuration - Allowing POST > 10Mb

Tags: java, jboss

Hoping somebody can point me in the correct direction here. Currently have a deployed app running on JBoss 4.2.3. The application now has a requirement to allow posts of sizes slightly larger than 10Mb. When the post is that size, it is disallowed on the client side.

I have tried setting the `maxPostSize` attribute to allow this but that has had no effect. My search through documentation has turned up no other suggestion.

If anybody has any suggestions, they'd be greatly appreciated.

Connector:

```
 <Connector port="443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
 scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" sslProtocol="TLS"    
 maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="16384"
 emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
 connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
 maxSavePostSize = "67108864" maxPostSize = "67108864" />
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/208035?_sscc=t) may help

Comment: Thanks BackSlash, I gave it a go but it has had no effect.